# av_seek_frame slow on large files

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg's c api to decode audio files. Everything is working well, except seeking on large files is quite slow. I have a 3 hour (450MB) mp3 file that I am testing with, and it takes about 12 seconds to seek from the start to near the end. Once I have seeked over parts of the file then any future seeks that are at an earlier part in the file are instantaneous. So it seems that ffmpeg is caching something to make future seeks fast.

```
int seek(uint64_t timestamp) {
    uint64_t seekTarget = av_rescale_q(timestamp * 1000, AV_TIME_BASE_Q, formatContext->streams[stream_index]->time_base);
    return av_seek_frame(formatContext, stream_index, seekTarget, AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY);
}
```

I have also tried `avformat_seek_file` and I get the same behavior. Is there any way to speed the seeking process up? Is there some extra information that I can give ffmpeg so it does not need to do so much work?

Comment: Are the files stored locally?

Comment: Yes, they are opened using `avformat_open_input`.